# When i publish the item I do not see changes (missing component on certain language)?

Tags: sxa, publishing

I am having this weird bug where I published my changes but I do not see those changes for that specific item on the site, and I also have this weird issue that in certain languages (in this example **en-US**) are not showing certain components, even though they exist on other cultures, for example **en-ca, en-mx...**.

What is the issue with the "not publishing" in Sitecore? I am using the Sitecore 9.3 version. I should see the changes but I do not, even though they are published to **web database**

UPDATE: This publishing does work on the `staging` but the changes will not be seen on the `live` site. Both sites are using the same **web database**

Comment: Have you tried clearing cache on your live server? You can use /admin/cache.aspx page for that

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the following Step-by-step guide to verify your publishing.

- Verify that your item is in the `final workflow` state if a workflow is
  specified. If no workflow is specific, then the workflow state should
  be empty.
- Verify that your item is publishable, or if a particular version is
  not getting published, make sure the version is publishable.
- Make sure your `publishing targets` are set correctly. By default, no
  publishing targets should be selected, which means `Sitecore` will
  deploy to all `publishing targets`. View the raw value of the
  `Publishing Targets` field, as sometimes an old, non-existing
  publishing target is specified and the UI will not show it. If there
  are any values specified for `Publishing Targets`, the best way to
  clear it is to reset the field.
- Make sure your `publishing targets` are set up correctly. Typically we
  have one publishing target named `Internet` and the target database is
  the web.
- Make sure your item name is valid. Sometimes we update the invalid
  characters list after items has been created.
- Make sure none of the parent items fail to publish.

Once you have verified all of these, you should be able to publish the item and it should show in the web database. If your item is in the web database and you are still unable to access the item via the web, check these items:

- Make sure your item name is valid. Sometimes we update the invalid
  characters list after items have been created and published. Item
  names with hyphens in particular usually cause issues.
- Make sure there aren’t any Sitecore Aliases are interfering (see
  `/sitecore/system/Aliases)`.

Comment: Thank you for this. The problem I do have is that the publish work on staging, but it does not work when I publish it on the live site. They are both using the same web database

Comment: Okay now when you updated your Question, I got more context. Can you check your logs and share something?

Comment: How to check logs in Sitecore? Or to be precise what is the best way to check the logs in Sitecore

Comment: You can check log in Sitecore under webroot folder path `\App_Data\logs\..`

Answer (score 0):

You already mentioned that, it is only happening with specific items that means your publishing targets are working fine.
Can you open and check that specific page in experience editor for master and  web DB(EE opens with master DB by default but you can manage it by adding query-string "sc_database=web" or "sc_database=master" )it will show the clear difference between master and web.
I think you are missing some related items that are not published.